# CNTK Sequence 2 Sequence Tutorial : placeholder_variable initialization

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, lstm, cntk

I am new to CNTK and was following [seq2seq tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb) of CNTK.

Inside the LSTM_layer function, there's following code :

```
dh = placeholder_variable(shape=(output_dim), dynamic_axes=input.dynamic_axes)
dc = placeholder_variable(shape=(output_dim), dynamic_axes=input.dynamic_axes)
LSTM_cell = LSTM(output_dim)    
f_x_h_c = LSTM_cell(input, (dh, dc))
h_c = f_x_h_c.outputs
```

Now, in `LSTM_Cell(input,(dh,dc))`:**what's the value for `dh` and `dc`**?

I don't find them getting initialized anywhere when LSTM_layer function is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a few lines below, you will find that the placeholders are replaced. At the time of model creation you may not have all the values needed but know the shape of the data you will need for that function to work. You create placeholders (containers) for those variables. Before executing the function, these values are replaced with variables that hold values to be computed.

```html
    replacements = { dh: h.output, dc: c.output }
    f_x_h_c.replace_placeholders(replacements)
```

Comment: And to further explain why we need to do it this way in an RNN, the dh and dc actually *don't* have values for t=1 because the RNN/LSTM update equation is defined using the hidden state's value at t-1 which doesn't exist. Therefore, for this first run through the RNN the network knows to replace that value with a default initial state.